# Do any visual studio plugins currenlty support auto refactoring from a variable to a property

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins

I am looking for a refactoring plugin which specifically has the ability to take a declaration like this:

```
Dim myVar as MyType
```

or

```
Private MyVar as MyType
```

and turn it into this:

```
Private _myVar as MyType
Private Property MyVar as MyType
   Get
      return _myVar
   End Get
   Set (ByVal value as MyType)
     _myVar = value
   End Set
 End Property
```

My examples are in VB however C# support would be greatly appreciated as well.

I am familiar with the VSS Template for Properties, however using that often feels slower than just typing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For free you can use the express edition of CodeRush to do this: [Get it here](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/). You want the "Encapsulate Field" refactor.

For cold, hard, cash the full version of CodeRush or [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will do this and much more. (I'd imagine there are other tools out there too, but this are the two I have experience with)

Comment: I had CodeRush Xpress already and missed this. It appears to be a multi-step process unless there is a keyboard shortcut for the refactoring. When I highlight a variable declaration it offers to promote to a field, then on a field I can generate setter methods.
Thanks.